# send() and recv() socket parameters

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm having some strange things happen with my program, and I'm not sure what I should be doing.  This is a pseudocode version of what my code looks like so far:

Server:

```
//Set up Server sockets

int maximum;

// Collect the maximum
cout << "\nEnter a Maximum:";
cin >> maximum;
cout << "\n";

int *array = new int[maximum + 1];

memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));

while(array[0] < anInt){

    //receive the array from the client
    if(recv(newsockfd, array, maximum, 0) < 0){
        perror("ERROR receiving from socket");
    }

    mathFunction(array);  //A function that alters the contents of array
    array[0]++;

    //If array[0] isn't too big
    if(array[0] < anInt){
        // Send the array to the client
        if(send(newsockfd, array, maximum, 0) < 0){
            perror("ERROR sending to socket");
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
//Set up Client sockets

//The maximum was already sent over earlier
int *array = new int[maximum + 1];

while(array[0] < anInt){

    //receive the array from the server
    if(recv(sockfd, array, maximum, 0) < 0){
        perror("ERROR receiving from socket");
    }

    mathFunction(array);  //A function that alters the contents of array
    array[0]++;

    if(send(sockfd, array, maximum, 0) < 0){
        perror("ERROR sending to socket");
    }
}
```

My problem is that I keep getting a "Connection reset by peer" error, which leads to a Segmentation Fault, crashing my program.  Also, when playing around with the 3rd argument of the send/recv functions (currently set as **maximum**), my program acts differently.  It will actually work perfectly if the user enters a maximum of 100, but anything more than that screws it up.

I know this is a long shot, but can anyone see something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which side gets the error and crashes? More detail, please.

Comment: That's one of the mysteries.  It happens on both sides, but just one or the other.

Comment: SIGSEGV must result from some actual code of yours. Not pseudocode, code. Connection reset by peer will happen on side (b) when side (a) crashes with SIGSEGV. Use a debugger and debug the SIGSEGV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all code that posted by you has a logical error:

Server first receive data from the client, do something with it and then send its result back to the client.

In the other side client also receive data from server, do something with it and then send it back to the server.

And that's obviously a race condition, no one send data to other side to begin communication.

Beside that logical error you have some C++ errors:

1) `memset(array, 0, sizeof(array))` only 0 initialize `sizeof(int*)` bytes from your array not entire array, since `sizeof(array)` is always `sizeof(int*)` if you want to 0 initialize entire array (and I think you want it) you should call:

```
memset(array, 0, (maximum + 1) * sizeof(int));
```

or even better:

```
std::fill( array, array + maximum + 1, 0 );
```

And in C++ it is much better to use classes like `std::vector` instead of raw pointers:

```
std::vector<int> array( maximum + 1 ); // automatically initialize to 0
```

2) Your array type is `int*` and `send/recv` count its input by byte, so if you want to `send/recv` entire array you must have something like:

```
send(sockfd, (char*)array, maximum * sizeof(int), 0);
```

3) You should check return value of `send/recv`, specially `recv` since it may `recv` less data in each call, for example you send 8K data and `recv` only receive first 1K and rest of it remain in the network buffer, so you should call it repeatedly until you read your buffer completely.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that seems obviously incorrect is:

```
mathFunction(array);
```

doesn't tell `mathFunction()` how many elements are in the array. In fact, you throw away this information when you call `recv()` by not storing it anywhere (all your code does is check to see if it's less than zero, but doesn't use it if it is positive). When calling `recv()`, your code must be prepared to receive *any number of bytes* from 1 through `maximum`. If you don't get all the bytes you ask for, then you need to call `recv()` again to get more.

Comment: mathFunction() is pseudocode.  In my actual code, it does it correctly.  My problem is with the **Connection reset by peer** error I'm getting.

Comment: So the code you posted isn't your real code? What about throwing away the return value of `recv()`? How do you expect us to help if we have to guess what is real and what is fake?

Comment: The real code would be pages long.  I was once "politely" asked not to post my real code here if it is too long and to use pseudocode instead.  I'm getting mixed signals.

Comment: At the very least, you could narrow down your problem to the location of where you get the SIGSEGV. I think that's the real problem (the "connection reset by peer" is likely the *result* of the SIGSEGV, not the cause).

Comment: I'm doing this for a school project and gdb isn't installed.  Any suggestions on what else I can use to debug it?

Comment: If gdb isn't installed (and you can't install it), then you'll have to find another way. One tried-and-true method is known as **"when in doubt, print more out"**. Print out messages showing where your program flow is going, what the values of key variables are, and if necessary, the contents of arrays or whatever. If your program crashes between output A and output B and you don't know why, add even more logging in between A and B. Through this divide-and-conquer approach, you'll be able to debug almost anything.